# Exception in Anonymous Inner class example

Tags: java, stack-overflow, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
public class outer {
    void meth(){
        System.out.println("outer");
    }

    outer y = new outer(){
        void meth(){
            System.out.println("anonymous");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        outer a = new outer();
        a.meth();
    }
}
```

When running above code I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I am trying to execute anonymous inner class in a single class; is that possible?
What would be the reason for this exception?

Comment: @hexafraction   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a new `outer` is constructed, the field `y` must be initialized, but that consists of creating *another* `outer` (or, rather, an anonymous subclass of `outer`). This continues indefinitely and causes a stack overflow.

Note that the error occurs on the first line of your `main`; `a.meth()` never even gets reached.

---

You can fix the code by not having `Outer` attempt to instantiate itself upon creation (you can, for example, make `y` `static`):

```
public class Outer {
    void meth(){
        System.out.println("outer");
    }

    static Outer y = new Outer(){
        void meth(){
            System.out.println("anonymous");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer a = new Outer();
        a.meth();
        y.meth();
    }
}
```

```
outer
anonymous
```

Note that I've assumed a more conventional naming scheme (i.e. `Outer` instead of `outer`).

Comment: So its not possible to write the same in single class file

Comment: @saurabhkumar You can (although logically you should probably separate out the `main`). The important thing is making `y` static. I've edited again.

Comment: static makes outer to create the object only one time ?that's the reason stackoverflow exception has gone ,am i right?

Comment: @saurabhkumar See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html.

Comment: sorry ,static in front of Outer y = new Outer() means ,we can call this without creating an object .am i right now?

Comment: @saurabhkumar No, it means `y` is not an *instance* variable but rather belongs to the class. This is explained in the link I put in my comment above.

Comment: ( When a new outer is constructed, the field y must be initialized...) here according to you what is 'outer' and 'y'?if y is not an instance variable then what it is?

Comment: When `y` is `static`, it is a *class variable*.